# В Chrome не работает анимация атрибута offset для линейного градиента

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Отвечая на вопрос: [Как анимировать градиентную непрозрачность в SVG?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1004966/28748)

столкнулся со странным поведением анимации атрибута `offset`

Ниже код, который прекрасно работает в Firefox, но любые попытки анимировать атрибут `offset` линейного градиента окончились ничем.

Подойдут любые решения данной проблемы с помощью: SVG, CSS, CSS3, JS

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 900 900" >  

 
<linearGradient id="bgg" x1="0" y1="0" x2="900" y2="900" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> 
  
 <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"/>
 <stop offset="52%" stop-color="white">
    <animate 
            attributeName="offset" 
            values="100%;0%;100%" 
            dur="4s" 
            repeatCount="indefinite">
    </animate> 
    </stop>  
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="gold">
        <animate 
            attributeName="offset" 
            values="100%;50%;100%" 
            dur="4s" 
            repeatCount="indefinite">
  </animate> 
    </stop> 
</linearGradient>

<rect x="50" y="50" width="50%" height="50%" rx="5%"  fill="url(#bgg)" />
</svg>
```

Пробовал также использовать проценты и `gradientUnits ="objectBoundingBox"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 900 900" >  

 <defs>
<linearGradient id="bgg" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"> 
  
 <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"/>
 <stop offset="52%" stop-color="white">
    <animate 
            attributeName="offset" 
            values="100%;0%;100%" 
            dur="4s" 
            repeatCount="indefinite">
    </animate> 
    </stop>  
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="gold">
        <animate 
            attributeName="offset" 
            values="100%;50%;100%" 
            dur="4s" 
            repeatCount="indefinite">
  </animate> 
    </stop> 
</linearGradient>
</defs>

<rect x="50" y="50" width="50%" height="50%" rx="5%"  fill="url(#bgg)" />
</svg>
```

Но это не принесло положительного результата в Chrome

В Firefox и этот вариант работает отлично.

Comment: @РустамГимранов ну тогда, наверное [официальная документация W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#LinearGradientNotes) по SVG предоставляет не валидные примеры. Я скорее поверю, что это с `Chrome`, что-то не так вместе с его экспериментальными технологиями

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#GradientStopAttributes

Comment: в примеры не добавили, однако в описании есть оба варианта

Comment: вот такой есть https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1002419/188366, или ты про именно svg?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ответ по ссылке видел и даже плюсовал :-) интересует решение `JS` смещения градиента с помощью `offset` атрибута, а не просто смещение градиента.  То есть надо забрать offset в переменную из SVG и изменять его программно.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131153/7394871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот решение на JS, тут нужна зависимость от времени, по которой мы будем менять атрибут:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(animateOffsets);

// если функция вызвана как колбек requestAnimationFrame, 
// то первым аргументом у нее идет время от старта сцены
function animateOffsets(t) { 
  requestAnimationFrame(animateOffsets);
  t = t%5000/5000; // будет меняться от 0 до 1 в течение 5 секунд
  t = Math.sin(t*Math.PI*2); // будет менятся от -1 до 1 
  stop1.setAttribute('offset', `${50 + t*50}%`);
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 900 900" >  
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="bgg" x1="0" y1="0" x2="60%" y2="60%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> 
    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="dodgerblue"/>
    <stop offset="50%" stop-color="white" id="stop1"/> 
    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="gold"/> 
  </linearGradient>
</defs>

<rect x="50" y="50" width="50%" height="50%" rx="5%"  fill="url(#bgg)" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

Опубликовал аналогичный вопрос на [англ. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131153/7394871)

Предложили интересное решение, - заменить проценты в параметре `values="100%;0%;100%"` на `values="1;0;1"`

И это решение стало работать в Chrome:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 900 900" >  

 <defs>
<linearGradient id="bgg" x1="0" y1="0" x2="50%" y2="50%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"> 
  
 <stop offset="0" stop-color="dodgerblue"/>
 <stop offset=".52" stop-color="white">
     <animate 
            attributeName="offset" 
            values="1;0;1" 
            dur="4s" 
            repeatCount="indefinite">
     </animate>
    </stop>  
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="gold">
        <animate 
            attributeName="offset" 
            values="1;.5;1" 
            dur="4s" 
            repeatCount="indefinite">
  </animate>
    </stop> 
</linearGradient>
</defs>

<rect x="50" y="50" width="50%" height="50%" rx="5%"  fill="url(#bgg)" />
</svg>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57131328/7394871): @enxaneta

Answer (score 5):

### Решение CSS

Вот идея только с CSS, где вы можете полагаться на два градиента и `translation/opacity animation`, чтобы добиться нужного эффекта:

```css
.box {
  border-radius:20px;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  width:220%;
  height:220%;
  animation:translate 2s infinite linear alternate;
}
.box:after {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,dodgerblue 0%,white 40%,gold 60%);
  animation-name:translate,show;
  opacity:0;
}
.box:before {
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,dodgerblue,white 50%,gold 50%);
}

@keyframes translate{
  from {
    transform:translate(48%,48%);
  }
}
@keyframes show{
  30%,85% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57132236/7394871): @Temani Afif