# Не работает transition по linear-gradient

Tags: css, css3, transition, linear-gradient

Всем привет!

Когда я использую смена цвета через `hover` таким образом:

```
.button {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #EEF2EE, #D4D4D4);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.button:hover{
    background: #FFDC29;
}
```

Мой элемент `buttom` становится прозрачным между обычным состоянием и `hover`.

Помогите правильно реализовать смену цвета, спасибо!

Comment: `background: linear-gradient(...)` — это `background-image`, а это `background: #FFDC29;` — `background-color`. Помимо прочего, даже если написать hover `background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFDC29, #FFDC29);` окажется, что градиент не анимируется) При желании можно быстро-быстро менять его значение из JS, и это будет казаться полноценной анимцией. Но решениие на JS длиннее предложенного ответа)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Обычно пользуются следующим трюком:

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #EEF2EE, #D4D4D4);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.button::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FFDC29;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: -1000;
}

.button:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">Button</div>
```

*Т.к transition по gradient'ам все еще не поддерживается.*

Comment: А я уж начал анимировать градиент в JS )

Comment: @Vasily Спасибо за ответ!) А если before уже занят, только через js?

Comment: @Samoilov, по идее можно и через after, нужно только будет проверить (во всех требуемых браузерах) не будет ли перекрытия текста (я не проверял). На крайний случай можно сделать три отдельных элемента и сложить их в нужно порядке один на другой (линейный фон, нелинейный фон, и текст) и так же анимировать opacity одного из фонов. Минус такого решения в том что это будет три элемента (плюс обертка) вместо одного.

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME для полноты картины можно сделать если захотите.

Comment: @Leks Хотел создать отдельный вопрос, нашел этот - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004966/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c ) Если уж SVG умеет, необходимость в JS отпадает. Хотя, чтобы реализовать на JS, как и в любой другой анимации, нужно просто уметь менять какие-то числа в течение времени: Всё упирается в вопрос, какую структуру данных использовать.